# elasticsearch: multifield mapping of multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping, elasticsearch-indices

i will have a document with multiple fields. let's say 'title', 'meta1', 'meta2', 'full_body'.
each of them i want to index in a few different ways (raw, stemming without stop-words, shingles, synonyms etc.). therefore i will have fields like: `title.stemming`, `title.shingles`, `meta1.stemming`, `meta1.shingles` etc.

do i have to copy paste the mapping definition for each field? or is it possible to create one definition of all ways of indexing/analysing and then only apply it to each of 4 top level fields? if so, how?

```
  mappings: 
    my_type: 
      properties: 
        title: 
          type: string
          fields: 
            shingles: 
              type: string
              analyzer: my_shingle_analyzer
            stemming:
              type: string
              analyzer: my_stemming_analyzer
        meta1:
           ...                   <-- do i have to repeat everything here?
        meta2:
           ...                   <-- and here?
        full_body:
           ...                   <-- and here?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you could use [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) with the `match_mapping_type` setting so that you can apply the same setting to all your string fields:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "strings": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                "shingles": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "my_shingle_analyzer"
                },
                "stemming": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "my_stemming_analyzer"
                }
                , ... other sub-fields and analyzers
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As a result, whenever you index a string field, its mapping will be created according to the defined template. You can also use the `match` setting, to restrict the mapping to specific field names, only.